# How to read messages from my Private Telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I am trying to read messages from my private telegram channel. I used the following code. I am facing a problem reading the message while it is in private but if I change the channel to the public this code is working fine. But I want the channel to be private is there any solution for this?

```
import configparser
import json
import re
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import (GetHistoryRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (PeerChannel)

api_id = *******
api_hash = ******

# Here you define the target channel that you want to listen to:
user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/<channel_id>'

client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)


# Listen to messages from target Channel
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
async def newMessageListner(event):
    # Get message text
    newMessage = event.message.message
    print(newMessage)


with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

while trying with the channel in private I am getting this error message

```
Cannot find any entity corresponding to "https://t.me/<channel_id>"
```

Note:
Channel ID is delibrately masked

Answer (score 1):

Add -100 before the channel Id like -100XXXXXXX

Comment: It worked. how did you find this out?

Comment: Super. I found this somewhere but I forgot where.